# My function doesn't change the value of the output variable

Tags: javascript

I'm new to coding so apologies for the really basic question.

I have made a javascript function called ErrorType that checks whether my variables 'correct' and 'response' equal 70 and 68 respectively. If they do, then I want to set 'correct_rule_wrong_resp' to 1.

My problem is that when I call the function, it has no effect on the value of 'correct_rule_wrong_resp'. Where am I going wrong?

```
    correct = 70;
    response = 68;
    correct_rule_wrong_resp = null;

    function ErrorType (a, b, c){
        if (correct == a && response == b){
            c = 1
        }
    }

    ErrorType (70, 68, correct_rule_wrong_resp)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605700/1871033

Comment: Changing the value of a scalar parameter you passed into your function, will not change any variables outside of the function. You need to _return_ the value from your function, and then do `correct_rule_wrong_resp = ErrorType(…);`

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Constants
const correct = 70;
const response = 68;
// Variable
let correct_rule_wrong_resp = null;

// Function
function ErrorType(a, b){
  if(correct == a && response == b){
      // Return result to function caller 
      return 1
  }
}

// Call function and assign returned value to your variable
correct_rule_wrong_resp = ErrorType(70, 68, correct_rule_wrong_resp);

// Test
console.log(correct_rule_wrong_resp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are not assing Any value to `correct_rule_wrong_resp`,
You are just calling function by passing variable